# how can i post data to same table in mysql using two different forms?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to save data using different forms in same table.If i inserted data using same table name in different form,data stored in database is not in a single row they are storing in multi rows.How can i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

use Insert .. On duplicate key update..

```
INSERT INTO table (a) VALUES (1)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE a=a+1;

UPDATE table SET a=a+1 WHERE a=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I got result by using update instead of insert then Iam able to update data in same row.Thank you